# Are there any use-cases for Array#push (unshift) without argument?

Tags: ruby

I am surprised to know Ruby's `Array#push` (and `Array#unshift`) can be invoked without argument and they do nothing.

In my opinion raising `ArgumentError` seems to be more appropriate behavior when no argument is passed to these methods (just like `append` in Python).

Are there any use-cases for `Array#push` (`Array#unshift`) without argument?

Comment: Let's reverse the question: is there any use-case for an `ArgumentError`? Why would that be desirable?

Comment: What if `Array#concat` with no argument does not raise `ArgumentError`? What if `Array#<<` with no argument does not cause `SyntaxError`? When the number of arguments provided is not appropriate to the intended specs, it should raise an exception like other methods.

Comment: `concat` and `<<` have an [`arity`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Method.html#method-i-arity) of 1, i.e. they have one required argument and cannot be invoked without it (Ruby ensures this, the method doesn't have to take care). `push` and `unshift` on the other hand have an arity of -1, i.e. they take a variable number of arguments, which always includes zero arguments. The method would have to check the argument count and raise an exception explicitly in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-push) clearly lists one mandatory parameter.

However, the [Ruby Spec Suite](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/array/push_spec.rb#L8) shows an example of passing 0 arguments.

The [MRI/YARV test suite](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/ruby/test_array.rb#L1185-L1188) also explicitly shows that passing 0 arguments should be possible, however there is a commented line that actually tests the opposite, namely that passing 0 arguments will raise an exception, and there is a comment which says that this feature was introduced in Ruby 1.8.

So, apparently, in Ruby 1.6 and earlier, there used to be one mandatory parameter, and Ruby 1.8 introduced the possibility of an arbitrary number of arguments. The only use-case I can think of is splatting a potentially empty array or `nil` without raising an error.

Comment: The use-cases you mention do not seem at all uncommon. For example, `[1,2].push(*[3,4,5].find { |x| x > 3 }) #=> [1, 2, 4]`, `[1,2].push(*[3,4,5].find { |x| x > 6 }) #=> [1,2]`, `[1,2].unshift(*[3,4,5].select(&:odd?)) #=> [3, 5, 1, 2]`, `[1,2].unshift(*[3,5,7].select(&:even?)) #=> [1,2]`.

Comment: It's not just splatting a potentially-empty array. All of the following return `["a", "b"]`: `["a", "b"].push(*{})`, `["a", "b"].push(*Set.new)` and `["a", "b"].push(*3..1)` (presumably because splat converts them all to arrays). However, `["a", "b"].push(*"") #=> ["a", "b", ""]`.